# change characters position and add space between them in c#

Tags: c#, .net

how would you change the position of the last two characters in a string and add space between them in c#?

for example, i have a simple string "apple" and it needs to be changed to "appe l".

I have tried several things but without any success.

thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: You said you *tried several things but without success*, would you mind providing your **code** and explaining how it *didn't work*? We then might be able to tell you **why** it didn't work, and **how** you can solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
string s = "apple";
s = $"{s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2)}{s[s.Length - 1]} {s[s.Length - 2]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string s = "apple";
        var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        var temp = sb[sb.Length - 2];
        sb[sb.Length - 2] = sb[sb.Length - 1];
        sb[sb.Length - 1] = temp;
        sb.Insert(s.Length - 1, " ");
        s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer adds anything to [Vikhram's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143756/7831383)

Comment: @Rafalon I posted it before him or started to write before him because he didn't post his answer when I started to write mine. I wouldn't post mine if I saw his answer. All questions to Stackoverflow

Comment: @LaurentLequenne i suppose so

Answer (score 0):

In C# `string` type is immutable, which means you cannot modify a string that is already created. If you need multiple modifications done, the usual way is to use `StringBuilder` class

```
string s = "apple";
var buf = new StringBuilder(s);
var ch = buf[buf.Length - 1];
buf[buf.Length - 1] = buf[buf.Length - 2];
buf[buf.Length - 2] = ch;
buf.Insert(s.Length - 1, ' ');
```

Comment: it works. how can i iterate on array i tried the following but its not working

Comment: using System;
    using System.Text;

   public class aa{
   public static void Main(){
 
       string[] s = new string[2];
        s[0] = "apple";
        s[1] = "google";
 foreach( string ss in s)
 {
   var buf = new StringBuilder(ss);
   var ch = buf[buf.Length - 1];
  buf[buf.Length - 1] = buf[buf.Length - 2];
  buf[buf.Length - 2] = ch;
  buf.Insert(ss.Length - 1, ' ');
  Console.WriteLine(ss);
 } 
  }
}

Comment: @YossiBondasd The modified string is in `buf`, but you seem to be printing `ss`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `string` into `char Array` by using `string.ToCharArray()` method. After this interchange last 2 characters and then add space between them, just like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fruit = "apple";
    char[] charFruit = fruit.ToCharArray();

    char temp = charFruit[charFruit.Length - 1]; // holds the last character of the string
    charFruit[charFruit.Length - 1] = charFruit[charFruit.Length - 2];  //interchnages the last two characters
    charFruit[charFruit.Length - 2] = temp;
    fruit = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < charFruit.Length; i++){
        if (i == charFruit.Length - 2){
            fruit += charFruit[i].ToString();
            fruit += " ";  
        }
        else
            fruit += charFruit[i].ToString();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```